# 3D gaussian generator/transform

Tags: random, gaussian

How do I generate 3 Gaussian variables? I know that the [Box-Muller algorithm](https://blog.cupcakephysics.com/computational%20physics/2015/05/10/the-box-muller-algorithm.html) can be used to convert two (U1,U2) uniform variables into two (X,Y) Gaussian variables but how do i generate the 3rd one? (Z).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A simple way:

It is unlikely in this sort of game that you will need 3 Gaussian variates just once.

You need some store variable that can contains either a triplet of Gaussian variates or *nothing* (Null, Nothing, Empty, whatever that is in your programming language, you didn't tell us which one).

Initially, the store contains nothing (empty).

When asked for a triplet:

- if the store contains a triplet, just return that triplet.
  And mark the store as empty.
- if the store is empty, run Box-Muller 3 times.
  That gives you 2 triplets.
  Put the second triplet in the store.
  Return the first triplet.

### An alternative way for the mathematically inclined programmer:

If one just tries to adapt Box-Muller to 3 dimensions, the sole tricky part is to get the *norm* of the random 3D vector. The rest is about the 2 spherical angles θ (theta) and φ (phi), which is easy stuff.

It turns out that in 3 dimensions, that norm involves the inverse of the [incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

And if you have Python and Numpy/Scipy, this is function [scipy.special.gammaincinv](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.gammaincinv.html).

We can thus write this code:

```
import  math
import  numpy.random   as  rd
import  scipy.special  as  sp

# convert 3 uniform [0,1) variates into 3 unit Gaussian variates:
def boxMuller3d(u3):
    u0,u1,u2 = u3    # 3 uniform random numbers in [0,1)

    gamma = u0
    norm2 = 2.0 * sp.gammaincinv(1.5, gamma)  # "regularized" versions
    norm  = math.sqrt(norm2)
    zr    = (2.0 * u1) - 1.0         # sin(theta)
    hr    = math.sqrt(1.0 - zr*zr)   # cos(theta)
    phi   = 2.0 * math.pi * u2
    xr    = hr * math.cos(phi)
    yr    = hr * math.sin(phi)

    g3 = list(map(lambda c: c*norm, [xr, yr, zr]))
    return g3

# generate 3 uniform variates and convert them into 3 unit Gaussian variates:
def gauss3(rng):
    u3 = rng.uniform(0.0, 1.0, 3)
    g3 = boxMuller3d(u3)
    return g3
```

To (partly) check correctness, we can have this small main program, which displays the statistical moments of order 1 to 4 of the resulting random serie:

```
randomSeed = 42
rng = rd.default_rng(randomSeed)

count = 3000000  #  (X,Y,Z) triplet count
variates = []
for i  in  range(count):
    g3 = gauss3(rng)
    variates += g3

ln = len(variates)
print("length=%d\n" % ln)

# Checking statistical moments of order 1 to 4:

m1 = sum(variates) / ln
m2 = sum( map(lambda x: x*x,   variates) ) / ln
m3 = sum( map(lambda x: x**3,  variates) ) / ln
m4 = sum( map(lambda x: x**4,  variates) ) / ln

print("m1=%g  m2=%g  m3=%g  m4=%g\n" % (m1,m2,m3,m4))
```

### Test program output:

```
length=9000000
m1=-0.000455911  m2=1.00025  m3=-0.000563454  m4=3.00184
```

We thus can see that these moments are reasonably close to their mathematically expected values, respectively 0,1,0,3.